# Remove factor from dataframe when it provides a certain value

Tags: r

I have following data

```
 head(df_raw)
  Scan                    Zeit Sensor Response
1    1 04.09.2019 06:28:22:405    101   9936.3
2    2 04.09.2019 06:28:32:389    101   9958.0
3    3 04.09.2019 06:28:42:389    101   9958.0
4    4 04.09.2019 06:28:52:389    101   9979.7
5    5 04.09.2019 06:29:02:389    101   9979.7
6    6 04.09.2019 06:29:12:389    101   9936.3
7    3 04.09.2019 06:28:42:389    102   9958.0
8    4 04.09.2019 06:28:52:389    102   9.9e+37
9    5 04.09.2019 06:29:02:389    102   9.9e+37
10    6 04.09.2019 06:29:12:389    102   9936.3
11    4 04.09.2019 06:28:52:389    103   7563.5
12    5 04.09.2019 06:29:02:389    103   9871.1
13    6 04.09.2019 06:29:12:389    103   10354.8
```

Sometimes, a sensor is broken and then it provides ~inf. numbers like `9.9e+37` or `9.900e+37`. When a sensor provides such a high value, even only one time, I want to remove that sensor from the dataframe.

Comment: Ah, sure,.. yeah, the second does the job. Totally forgot this very basic command :) I had to use python for the last year... thank you!

Comment: In the end I would recommend something like this: `!grepl("e\\+37", formatC(c(101, 9.9e+37)))`

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out. I figured an issue in such a way that sensors with these high values sometimes provide reasonable values in their data. So I think it is not sufficient to exclude data with those high values but exclade an factor completely when it provides such a single value.

Comment: Could you rephrase the question in a way that makes it reproducible and more clear what you are asking? On a personal note, I would recommend to check out the `validate` package: https://github.com/data-cleaning/validate to set up workflows for these kinds of issues

Comment: Yes, changed the question and will have a look at the package.

Comment: Rest of the values seem quite normal (distributed)...why not do an anomaly detection?

Comment: For which purpose? A value of 9.9e+37 will only appear when the sensor has some faulty electronical properties. So I just want to exclude them from the further analysis.

Comment: If you use anomaly detection, you are generalising this beyond the `9.9e+37`. So If a value of `9.9e+38` appears somehow, then the anomaly detection will still find that...Once captured, you can do whatever...eliminate them, keep them, etc...

Comment: 9.9e+37 is a value the measurement device provides when there happened an error (mostly a short).

Comment: What if the device gets updated/changed and the new value is different? :) Anw..I was just giving my 2 cents for as more generalized solution as possible. Also note a mathematical oriented solution will also be much more efficient than any regex

Comment: with the any() function it should work, just have to figure out how to use it factor-wise

Comment: It won't get updated as the measurements are taken only once ;) It is quality assurance.

Comment: Then why use `any`? Why not simply `df[df$Response != 9.90000e+37,]`?

Comment: Indeed. I thought it would "only" remove all according rows instead of the entire factor. Yeah, it seems that it is sufficient..  lol :) Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. It will remove rows with that value...

Comment: ..maybe I have to check again. What I need is that a sensor will be removed from the dataframe when it provides such a value, even only once. The sensor is a factor with several levels which correspond to the individual sensors. 101 is a sensor, 102 is another sensor, 103 is another sensor and so on..

Comment: Indeed again,.. yeah, that's not sufficient as it will keep the rows which are < 9.9e+37. I need the entire factor to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove the entire sensor, then you can do

```
df[!df$Sensor %in% (df$Sensor[df$Response == 9.90000e+37]),]
```

which will remove all `102` sensors as shown below,

> ```
>    Scan                   Zeit Sensor Response
> 1     1 04.09.201906:28:22:405    101   9936.3
> 2     2 04.09.201906:28:32:389    101   9958.0
> 3     3 04.09.201906:28:42:389    101   9958.0
> 4     4 04.09.201906:28:52:389    101   9979.7
> 5     5 04.09.201906:29:02:389    101   9979.7
> 6     6 04.09.201906:29:12:389    101   9936.3
> 11    4 04.09.201906:28:52:389    103   7563.5
> 12    5 04.09.201906:29:02:389    103   9871.1
> 13    6 04.09.201906:29:12:389    103  10354.8
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably smarter ways but an easy way to proceed is:

Convert values to NA

```
df_raw[df_raw == 9.9e+37]<- NA
```

Remove columns with NA

```
not_any_na <- function(x) all(!is.na(x))
df_raw<- df_raw %>%
                    select_if(not_any_na)
```